# Electric potential and Electric Fields in Concentric Shells

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

If two conducting shells are concentric and of opposite charge, can someone tell me the electric field and electric potential in the regions: within the smaller shell, between the shells, and outside the big shell in terms of radius and charge. (The inner shell has a charge of lower magnitude)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This site is primarily for questions on concepts in physics that may be applicable to a broad audience, and less so homework help.

What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Bob well I managed to figure out the electric potential but I'm still struggling with the electric fields. I think you have to use Gauss's law for this one but I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Within the smaller shell there is no electric field. Between the shells it is charge on the smaller shell $Q$ divided by $4 r^2 \pi \epsilon$. $\epsilon$ absolute permittivity of medium between the shells. Outside the big shell it is again zero. All follows easily from Gauss's law.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you explain why outside the big shell is zero?

Comment: The answer is pretty complete as is.  I’m sure you can look up the remaining details.

Comment: @Dannnnnnn - Would be interesting to know the reasons why you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: The answer partially wrong. If you have two concentric conducting shells of opposite charge, there is going to be an electric field on the outside of the shell.

Comment: @Dannnnnnn - Not if the total charge on the two shells sums up to zero as in this case.  Its just Gauss's law outside the two shells with zero total charge within the Gauss enclosure.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps I should’ve been more clear in the question.

Comment: @ Dannnnnnn - So what is then your question?

Comment: Your answer lead to the discovery of my own answer. I guess there is no more need for this post anyone.